# How to get the native version of Spotify running?

Tags: apt, software-installation, spotify

A while ago Spotify (the streaming music service) came out with a preview for Linux of their client.

So what should I do?

Comment: Yup, I'm aware :)  I've seen a screenshot of someone running the native spotify client, however I can't even get the repository to work correctly :(

Comment: Note: The Linux client for Spotify only works if you have a premium account. This is because they have not found a way to reliably display ads.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Spotify in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815181/how-do-i-install-spotify-in-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: @JorgeCastro: we're using this one as the canonical one: you're creating a circular reference.  **:-)**

Comment: Or just merge them?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I installed it yesterday fine. The error you're getting is it's trying to get the source version (which doesn't exist). Just edit your sources using: `sudoedit /etc/apt/sources.list`

And make sure you've got something like this:

```
deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
# deb-src http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
```

The second (`deb-src`) line is commented. Make sure yours is and then run a `sudo apt-get update`. You shouldn't get any errors.

Make sure the key is installed (doesn't sound like your problem):

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys D2C19886
```

And then install it:

```
sudo apt-get install spotify-client-qt spotify-client-gnome-support
```

Comment: I've done that, but whilst I'm not getting the error anymore, I'm not getting the packages :/

Comment: I tell a lie, my terminal seemingly has concussion and has now installed the packages :D

Comment: no command found deb 11.04 any help?

Comment: @scwiz That's not a command, it's supposed to be a line in the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: Edited this to use `apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 4E9CFF4E` as in the [official instructions](http://www.spotify.com/fi/download/previews/). (The gpg commands didn't work for me; apparently wwwkeys.de.pgp.net didn't respond.)

Comment: `spotify-client-gnome-support` wouldn't install on my 11.04 ("Depends: spotify-client-qt (= 1:0.5.2.84.g6d797eb-1) but 1:0.6.2.291.gcccc1f5.116-1 is to be installed. E: Broken packages"), but even without it Spotify works great (at least the main thing about it: music). +1 for the instructions!

Comment: @Jonik I think that's just version lag. Hopefully they'll release a new version of `spotify-client-gnome-support` that is built against the right version of `spotify-client-qt` (which is the main version)

Comment: Does anyone know if it's possible to download and install this key using https?

Comment: If your `sources.list` file is starting to look messy or unmanageable, or if you just like to keep third party sources separate, instead of editing your `sources.list` file, try this: `echo "deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list`

Comment: Instead of editing sources.list manually you can use the command `sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free"`

Answer (score 3):

Sure thing, i'm listening to it as i write this! Define this source for Apt

`deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free`

Then your usual apt update routine (GUI tools like Software Center do this for you), and install the packages *spotify-client-qt* and *spotify-client-gnome-support*. Sometimes it's a little buggy and eats loads of CPU, or doesn't draw it's main window at startup, but in general it works great.

There has been several mentions of Spotify over at [OMG Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/?s=spotify).

Comment: I've tried that, but this is what I get:

Failed to fetch http://repository.spotify.com/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'non-free/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: I can navigate to http://repository.spotify.com/dists/stable/non-free/binary-i386/ and apt fetches the file successfully with "apt-get download spotify-client-qt". You're not trying to use a source repo, are you?

Comment: Solved!  When I was adding the repo, the software sources was automatically adding a "source" line as well, which isn't in the Releases file  in dists/stable, so it was failing.  I've removed that line and now it's working :)

Comment: what to do now i am new do u have a step by step introduction cheers would be awsome
thank u

Comment: Also, if you want it to be integrated with the sound menu and work with your media controls (play/pause, etc. on keyboard), you can use spotify-notify. http://code.google.com/p/spotify-notify/

Comment: There are slightly [better instructions in this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7489/how-to-get-spotify-running/7494#7494) (including how to add encryption key, etc). Spotify's [official instructions](http://www.spotify.com/fi/download/previews/) are fully comprehensive too.

Answer (score 3):

To install the Spotify snap package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install spotify
```

#### Features of the Spotify free version

- Play any song, artist, album or playlist instantly
- Choice of three audio streaming quality options.

  1. normal audio quality (160 kbps)
  2. *paid subscribers can also select high quality streaming (320 kbps)*
  3. *or lossless audio (1,411 kbps)*
- Browse hundreds of ready-made playlists in every genre and mood
- Stay on top of the charts
- Stream radio
- Enjoy podcasts, audiobooks and videos
- Discover more music with personalized playlists

Answer (score 0):

This should help you obtain the Spotify Linux preview:

http://www.spotify.com/uk/download/previews/

However, If I remember correctly the Linux preview doesn't actually do much and doesn't actually function. Spotify currently recommends you install the Windows version through Wine:

This documentation from Spotify should help you:

http://www.spotify.com/uk/help/faq/wine/

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having trouble, what I ended up doing that worked was removing all instances in my software and sources of spotify repositories. From there I just re-added the repository by clicking add and then typing in `deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free`. 
I refreshed the window, opened up terminal, typed

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install spotify-client
```

and everything worked just fine

Answer (score 0):

You can also install the very latest Spotify version from the `testing` PPA :

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys D2C19886
echo deb http://repository.spotify.com testing non-free | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install spotify-client
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i have just installed Spotify on my machine sucessfully.

```
# 1. Add the Spotify repository signing keys to be able to verify downloaded packages
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 931FF8E79F0876134EDDBDCCA87FF9DF48BF1C90

# 2. Add the Spotify repository
echo deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list

# 3. Update list of available packages
sudo apt-get update

# 4. Install Spotify
sudo apt-get install spotify-client
```

Spotify official **Documentation** [here](https://www.spotify.com/int/download/linux/)

Comment: `GPG error: http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY D1742AD60D811D58` As of 2021, this does not work.