# How do I install the native Spotify application?

Tags: 11.04, spotify

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the native version of Spotify running?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7489/how-to-get-the-native-version-of-spotify-running)

Has anyone managed to install Spotify in Ubuntu 11.04 Beta?  The software source doesn't appear to work, thus not allowing me to install it from their repository.

If you know how to do it successfully, any help will be greatly welcomed :)