# Can't install Spotify Linux preview

Tags: spotify

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the native version of Spotify running?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7489/how-to-get-the-native-version-of-spotify-running)

I'm having trouble installing the [Spotify Linux preview](http://www.spotify.com/uk/download/previews/).

I'm kinda new to Ubuntu so I'm not sure if I did something wrong.

First, in the terminal, I ran this:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

At the bottom, I added this:

```
deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
# deb-src http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
```

Then I ran this:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 4E9CFF4E
```

Next:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

It seemed to have gone well, as there were no error messages.

So next, I ran this:

```
sudo apt-get install spotify-client-qt
```

But when I did, I got this:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 spotify-client-qt : Depends: spotify-client but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Any ideas?

**Edit**

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10, and yes, I had the same error message the user had in that question:

> Failed to fetch http://repository.spotify.com/dists/stable/Release Unable to find expected entry non-free/source/Sources in Meta-index file (malformed Release file?) Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

I added the `#` before the second line (which wasn't there) and I no longer received that error message.

Also, in reply to Bahaïka's comment, I ran that command (`sudo apt-get install spotify-client`) and I got the following:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 spotify-client : Depends: libqt4-webkit (>= 4.5.0) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libssl0.9.8 but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libavcodec53 but it is not going to be installed or
                          libavcodec52 but it is not installable
                  Recommends: libavformat53 but it is not going to be installed or
                              libavformat52 but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Look to my answer, I just edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good package is called only "spotify-client" you can remove the "qt" part.

```
sudo apt-get install spotify-client
```

As you can see at this ouput, the QT one was a transitional package :

```
$ apt-cache search spotify-client
spotify-client - Spotify desktop client
spotify-client-gnome-support - Transitional package for spotify-client
spotify-client-qt - Transitional package for spotify-client
```

**EDIT**

According to this : http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libqt4-webkit
You'll have to enable the universe repository.
Go into the software source and activate it.

This is what there is inside my /etc/apt/sources.list :

```
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric universe
deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric universe
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates universe
deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates universe
```

Comment: I received an error message when attempting to do so, see my edit in the original question.

Comment: It installed perfectly after I did that, thank you so much!