# Why have all my files become read-only?

Tags: filesystem

I was trying to install Spotify onto my ubuntu...and I don't know what I did wrong, but I do not have Spotify and all of my files have become read-only (everything in the file system has a padlock on it)!!! This means I cannot do anything in the terminal without getting the error that it cannot open anything because it’s a read-only file system...any suggestions?

Thanks for replying so fast! I tried to follow these instructions on terminal ..none of the stuff was working anyway

> Debian
>
> ```
> # 1. Add this line to your list of repositories by
> #    editing your /etc/apt/sources.list
> deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
>
> # 2. If you want to verify the downloaded packages,
> #    you will need to add our public key
> sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 94558F59
>
> # 3. Run apt-get update
> sudo apt-get update
>
> # 4. Install spotify!
> sudo apt-get install spotify-client
> ```

Now I keep getting this error if I try and do an `fsck`:

> permission denied while trying to open /dev/sda1 you must have r/w access to the file system or be root.

I think the error happened when it kept telling me dev is not recognised so I tried to install devscripts...:( ...which was what someone else suggested (if you're having trouble installing spotify)

My history is just the following

```
24  vi/etc/apt/sources.list
25  deb
26  debc (spotify link) stable non-free
27  sudo apt-get install devscripts
28  debc http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
29  deb (spotify link) stable non-free
30  apt-get install debian-reference
31  yes
32  sudo apt-key adv--keyserver.ubuntu.com--recv-keys 4E9CFF4E
33  sudo add-apt-repository "deb (spotify link) stable non-fr
```

Comment: Not possible to answer without knowing what you did to attempt installing spotify. Did you follow some guide you found on the net? do you have a link to it? Did you run commands in a terminal? if so, what were those commands?

Comment: You might have accidentally done a recursive chmod of sorts. Type in **history** to the terminal and post any commands you might have used to change permissions.

Comment: I edited the answer above... i'll post all the history too. thanks for getting back so fast

Comment: where i've put "spotify link" it refers to http://repository.spotify.com ...i cant post links more than twice..

Comment: take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/7489/how-to-get-the-native-version-of-spotify-running

Comment: wont help because now I have no access to file system dont care about spotify anymore...need to get access to my file system! thanks though!

Comment: padlock image on my system folders is gone but I still have no access on terminal to anything...

Comment: still cant save new files

Comment: tried to do a back up just in case but my entire filesystem is read only so i cant even use a USB drive

Answer (score 1):

This can happen because there is a disk drive error. What you describe has happened several times to me. Your fstab will have an entry similar to this:

UUID=80e377f3-6e78-4126-aa93-35ee62b58272 /  ext4    errors=remount-ro 0 1

This is an instruction to remount the drive read-only if there are errors.
In my case this was caused by faulty sata connections to the motherboard. I reseated the sata connector and the problem went away.

But the problem kept coming back and I finally solved the problem for good, by buying new, high quality sata cables that had a spring locking clip in the connectors. YMMV :)

Answer (score 0):

Type `ls -l` in one of the padlocked directories to find out the permissions. You should be able to change them with `chmod` and `chown` (using `sudo` if not owned by your user) if they are wrong.

For example, if a file that should be writable says:

```
-r--r--r-- 1 user user  4160 Jul 18 15:44 file.ext
```

You can give yourself write permissions using `chmod ug+w file.ext`.

If a file that belongs to you says:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root user  4160 Jul 18 15:44 file.ext
```

You can take control of it using `sudo chown user file.ext`.

Similarly `chgrp` to change the group (the second 'user' above) if that is wrong.