# Why do I get unmet dependencies installing spotify on 12.10?

Tags: installation, 12.10, dependencies, gconf, spotify

I followed the instructions to install spotify as on various forums & sites, pretty much the same steps everywhere. But when I get to the install spotify line, this is what happens:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 spotify-client : Depends: libgconf2-4 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What is `libgconf2-4` and how do I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Take a look at [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](http://askubuntu.com/q/140246/62483) In that post you should find a solution for your problem. If you still have troubles, or if you did solved the issue, let us know by creating a new comment here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the native version of Spotify running?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7489/how-to-get-the-native-version-of-spotify-running)

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. What's wrong here is that Spotify cannot run without the package `libgconf2-4`. This is because Spotify *depends* on that package. It would be like running an application like Minecraft without previously installing the package `libgconf2-4`. You can download `libgconf2-4` from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libgconf2-4).

Get the package according to what version of Ubuntu you have. After you install `libgconf2-4`, Spotify should install, and you can get to your music!

Answer (score 0):

> ### Installing Spotify

The first step is to open Software Sources via the Unity Dash:

[image]

Select the ‘Other Software’ tab in Software Sources **1**

[image]

Click ‘Add’ **2** and paste the following the entry field of the box that appears:

```
  deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
```

Click ‘Add Source’ to confirm the change, then close Software Sources.

> ### Add Spotify Repo Key

The next step is to add the repository key to verify that packages installed from this PPA are by whom they say.

Open a new Terminal window

Paste the following, then hit return/enter:

```
 sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 94558F59
```

That’s that! You can now install Spotify through the Ubuntu Software Center (after checking for software updates first) or by running the following command in the Terminal window:

```
 sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install spotify-client
```

Once installed you can launch Spotify from the Unity Dash.

## [Source : OMG Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/01/how-to-install-spotify-in-ubuntu-12-04-12-10)

## [A sneak peek into Spotify's secret labs](https://www.spotify.com/int/download/previews/)