# Spotify for Ubuntu

Tags: spotify

I'd like to use Spotify with Ubuntu. I've had a look at the previous questions and answers and don't understand the language - sorry.
 Is it possible to have step by step instructions? 
I use Linux not through any desire to be a programer but more a sense of 'rebel forces against the evil empire' :-)

Comment: For recent arrivals who just want to listen to spotify on Ubuntu, there is a web client, play.spotify.com which works fine, however it does require a flash enabled browser.

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free"
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 94558F59
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install spotify-client
```

note:
this worked for Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr (April 20, 2014)

Comment: I suggest you copy (or even move) this answer to http://askubuntu.com/questions/7489/how-to-get-the-native-version-of-spotify-running as this offers a clearer and up-to-date solution. BTW it also worked for Ubuntu 14.10 ;-)

Comment: Ubuntu 15.04 AMD64 was unable to open spotify client.
<code>root@xxxxx:/# spotify</code>
<code>spotify: error while loading shared libraries: libgcrypt.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory</code>