# Can't install packages in Lubuntu

Tags: apt, lubuntu

I installed Lubuntu yesterday and updated it.

Whenever I run `sudo apt-get update` and afterwards `sudo apt-get install spotify` (for example), I get `E: Impossible to get package "spotify-client"` (roughly translated from my native language).

I have used ubuntu before amongst other distros but this is the first time it happened to me. I had the same error while trying to install filezilla and arandr.

Any idea on this one?

Comment: There is no package called `spotify` or `spotify-client` on the main repos. Filezilla, on the other hand, *is* in the repos. Are you using a PPA?

Comment: [How to get the native version of Spotify running?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7489/how-to-get-the-native-version-of-spotify-running) or https://www.spotify.com/download/previews/

Answer (score 2):

There is no spotify client in the official repositories.

However if you are using 14.04 you can add the repository by going

Update manager --> Settings

Select the "Other Software" tab click on add and add this

```
deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
```

Now you need to add the keys so open a terminal and enter

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 94558F59
```

Enter your password when asked.

Now enter these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install spotify-client
```

source [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/install-spotify-ubuntu-14-04/)