# Katoolin tools borked spotify: how to uninstall?

Tags: kali, kali-linux-tools

What I did was:

1. Install the Kali Linux tools on my ubuntu 18.04 LTS using the katoolin tool.
2. Then I installed all the information gathering tools using the katoolin script.
3. The thing is that when I try to run the spotify application on my ubuntu system, I get:

   ```
   Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "gail" Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"  (spotify:15787): 
   Gtk-WARNING: cannot open display: :0
   ```
4. I have installed gail and atk-bridge lib but this issue is a pain. I have tried every possible like removing packages and etc. It does not work still.
5. Also i cannot open the gnome-system-monitor application:

   ```
   Unable to init server: Unable to create socket: Permission denied
   (gnome-system-monitor:21244): Gtk-WARNING: 23:42:41.547: cannot open display: :0
   ```

*How should I proceed getting my system back to normal?*

Comment: I just edited the post please have a look now and let me know

Comment: @AbhijeetSinghTomer I don't know if this question can be reopened. I read it before you edited it. It was unclear, so I ignored it. It's not unclear anymore, so I can answer it. You don't need either katoolin or gail because spotify is a native Ubuntu package. To install spotify open the terminal and type `sudo snap install spotify`

Comment: @karel . I have already installed it. But when i run this application i get this error. The thing is that. So what should i do now?

Comment: @karel reopened and edited.  Ping me after answering;

Answer (score 1):

#### Warning about updates after installing Kali linux tools

The [LionSec Katoolin GitHub](https://github.com/LionSec/katoolin) webpage clearly warns Katoolin users to be careful when updating software.

> Before updating your system, please remove all Kali-linux repositories to avoid any kind of problem.

[image]

All kinds of problems can occur if you don't do this.

---

The Katoolin script is the cause of some of your problems. You don't need the repositories that the Katoolin script added anymore, so restore your sources.list file in `/etc/apt/sources.list` back to the default for a fresh installation of Ubuntu 18.04.

1. Make a backup copy of sources.list.

   ```
   sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bak
   ```
2. Open `/etc/apt/sources.list` for editing in nano text editor:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```
3. Replace the entire contents of your existing sources.list with the following default 18.04 sources.list:

   ```
   deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted universe multiverse  
   deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
   deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
   deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse  
   deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
   ```

   Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file being edited. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.
4. Run this command after changing sources.list to refresh the list of available software. This is the most important step, so please don't skip it.

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```

After running the above commands the package management in your Ubuntu 18.04 should go back to normal.

---

#### Spotify

You got the following error message:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "gail" Gtk-Message:   
  Failed to load module "atk-bridge" (spotify:15787):   
Gtk-WARNING: cannot open display: :0
```

It looks like the Spotify snap package might work again after switching the channels. Run the following command to switch the spotify snap package's channel:

```
sudo snap switch spotify --edge
```

Comment: As promised!  **;-)**

Comment: After following the same step you provided still throws the same error. It does not work. Now what should i do. ?

Comment: [How to get the native version of Spotify running?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7489/)